# Correct intent to show only Audio files

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pick `Audio` from Gallery. I am using the following intent.

```
private void selectAudioFromGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("audio/3gp, audio/AMR, audio/mp3");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.select_audio_file_title)), REQ_CODE_PICK_SOUNDFILE);

    }
```

I want to select files of type `3gp, AMR, mp3` and only these files should be listed in the file chooser but the problem I am facing it, it also shows the other files too like text files, image etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
    Intent intent = null;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
         intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    }else {
         intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    }

    // The MIME data type filter
    intent.setType("audio/*")
```

Works..

Comment: Work like charm

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
intent.setType("audio/3gp|audio/AMR|audio/mp3");
```

Adding multiple mime type need pipe sign, not comma.

**Another way**

```
intent.setType("audio/*");
String[] mimetypes = {"audio/3gp", "audio/AMR", "audio/mp3"};
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
```

Comment: *I want to select files of type 3gp, AMR, mp3 and only these files should be listed* - this won't achieve that

Comment: @TimCastelijns: updated my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Rohit5k2: It still showing me File Manger in the chooser dialog, with File Manager I can pick any file i want. How Can I restrict that?

Comment: Both solutions are not restricting application for audio mime type. Chooser shows the File Manager and user can attached any type of file